# Send alerts in GetServerSideProps in whilst redirect?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I created a component that redirects users that are not logged in in getServerSideProps. I was wondering what I could do to display an alert on the page that the user is redirected to. I redirect users using

```
    try {
      const user = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser();
    } catch (err) {
      res.writeHead(302, {
        Location: "/contests/0/error",
      });
      res.end();
    }
```

Comment: Would you always want the alert to be shown when accessing the page you're redirecting to? Would the alert be always the same or change?

Answer (score 2):

One of the possible options would be adding a query string. Then you can check the existence of the query inside of the '/contests/0/error' page.
If it is there, just show an alert.

Let's say you want to say 'You are not authanticated', you can add it like:

```
try {
  const user = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser();
} catch (err) {
  res.writeHead(302, {
    Location: "/contests/0/error?msg=You%20are%20not%20authanticated",
  });
  res.end();
}
```

Another approach, instead of redirecting from getServerSideProps, you can return the error message as property and set it to your global state (maybe redux?). After that, you can redirect to an error page and you can reach check and get that state inside of your error page

Let me demonstrate it for you,

```
// getserversideprops

try {
  const user = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser();
} catch (err) {
  return {
    props: {error: 'You are not authanticated'}
  }
}


// initial page

const Page = (props) => {
  const { error } = props;

  if (error) {
    setErrorToGlobalState(error); // setting it to globals state to get error inside of the error page
    redirectToTheErrorPage(); // redirect to that error page
  }

  // ...rest of the code
}


// error page

const ErrorPage = () => {
   const {error} = globalState;

   if (error) {
    showAlert(error)
   }

}
```

I would suggest you implement the query option, but this is another way to solve it. I hope it helps.

Comment: would there be an alternative where I would not use query strings?

Comment: What's the reason why you wouldn't use it? You could remove the query string on the page you're redirecting to if needed.

Comment: With query string approach: i check for them in my component and show an alert. But i am not able to remove them after that. They always stay in query params. And when you refresh you will see the alert again which shouldn't happen, atleast in mycase.